# Two syntax errors in my python code

Tags: python, syntax-error

I've written a small program in python 3.2 that takes numbers as an input and counts them by a user chosen amount. For some reason I've been getting some syntax errors.

Here's the code.

```
    start = input(int("Starting number: "))
    ending = input(int("Ending number: "))
    tick = input(int(("Interval: "))
    print("Counting by", tick)
    print(for i in range(start, ending, tick):
        print(i, end = " ")
```

The errors occur in the print functions for "Counting by" and for i in range. In addition the colon on the fifth line is also seen as a syntax error.

Comment: What is the for loop supposed to do?

Comment: `print(for i in range(start, ending, tick):` is absolutely wrong syntax.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: @S. Lott I could have sworn I put the correct number of parenthesis in there. Must've missed one.

Comment: It's not just the unmatched paren. You can't have a `:` after a `print` call.

Comment: There's a trick that will prevent you from having to swear you did it correctly.  Actually copy and paste the actual code you're actually using.  Also, actually copy and paste the actual error message you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start = int(input("Starting number: "))
ending = int(input("Ending number: "))
tick = int(input("Interval: "))
print("Counting by", tick)
for i in range(start, ending, tick):
    print(i, end = " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an unmatched '(' in line 3.

Your `for` loop shouldn't be in a `print` function call.

This isn't a syntax problem, I don't think, but you should have `int(input(...))` instead of `input(int(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
start = input(int("Starting number: "))
ending = input(int("Ending number: "))
tick = input(int(("Interval: ")))
print("Counting by %d" % tick)
for i in range(start, ending, tick):
    print(i, end = " ")
```

Still a syntax error on the last line, but that's because I'm not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to print the numbers in sequence.

Comment: Then you can just change that to `print(i)`. You're right @Fred. I forgot to make sure I was running the example in the right Python version. Whoops.

Comment: `print(i)` would be the equivalent of `print i` in Python 2. I think the intent is the equivalent of `print i,`.